# Problem with SPO Document Library default view not saving column positions

Tags: sharepoint-online, spo

This seems like it should be a pretty easy task -

I have created a new document library in SPO and added a few columns to it.  When I move the columns around, or hide various columns, and the leave the site and return, the column order that I had previously set is not maintained, and the hidden columns are visible again.

This is a new site and I have complete rights to it.

Is there something I'm just overlooking here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your description you just forgot one little thing: to save the modification.

In SharePoint you even have to save such small modifications on a library view like sorting or hiding columns.
If you have to save such changes you can easyly see by looking at the view name.

When there is a asterics on the name, there are changes that have to be saved to be active when leaving and returning to that view.

Click on it, choose 'Save view as' and save it with the actual name to override the view configuration.
[image: Save view modification]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, what you outlined makes sense.  The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to follow the steps you've outlined I'm getting a correlation error -

Correlation ID: 8f8d0b9f-2078-9000-b528-8412cc11656b

Since we're running SPO, I'm not sure how to track this one down.

Comment: Then there is a whole other problem with your SiteCollection or at least your List. Try it again on another list. If it works you know what to do.
If not, try again with another SiteCollection.
 If you still have error while performing such simple functions (saving a list view etc.) I guess you should contact Microsoft support.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new view where you arrange the columns as per your requirement and set it as the default view.

OR

You can modify the existing view.

[image]

You can do the above from library settings as well.

Comment: As I mentioned to MP_89,  what you've both outlined makes sense.  The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to follow the steps you've outlined I'm getting a correlation error -

Correlation ID: 8f8d0b9f-2078-9000-b528-8412cc11656b

Since we're running SPO, I'm not sure how to track this one down.

Comment: see comment down below